# How do I remove duplicate records and only take the one with the higest revision number

Tags: select, sql-server-2005, group-by, distinct

I would like to only have one record returned for each VariableName, and it needs to be the highest revision number. I have tried GROUP BY and DISTINCT, but nothing seems to work.

I have this SQL Code

```
    SELECT Docs.DocID
      ,Filename
      ,VName
      ,VText
      ,RevNo
  FROM Docs
  INNER JOIN VarVal ON Docs.DocID = VarVal.DocID
  INNER JOIN Vars ON Vars.VarID = VarVal.VarID
  WHERE Docs.DocID in (
                                    select DocID
                                    from Docs
                                    INNER JOIN VarVal on Docs.DocID = VarVal.DocID
                                    INNER JOIN Var on Var.VarID = VarVal.VarID
                                    where VarName = '07'
                                    and ValueText = '801016'
                                )
  AND Docs.Deleted = 0
  AND Var.IsDeleted = 0
  ORDER BY VName
```

That produces this result
[image: this is the query result]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Docs.DocID
  ,Filename
  ,VName
  ,VText
  ,(Select Top 1 RevNo
    Where 
    Docs.DocID = D.Docs.DocID And
    VName=D.VName And
    VText = D.Vtext
    From Docs
    Order by RevNo 
    )

FROM Docs as D
INNER JOIN VarVal ON Docs.DocID = VarVal.DocID
INNER JOIN Vars ON Vars.VarID = VarVal.VarID
WHERE Docs.DocID in (
                                select DocID
                                from Docs
                                INNER JOIN VarVal on Docs.DocID = VarVal.DocID
                                INNER JOIN Var on Var.VarID = VarVal.VarID
                                where VarName = '07'
                                and ValueText = '801016'
                            )
AND Docs.Deleted = 0
AND Var.IsDeleted = 0
ORDER BY VName
```

Comment: this doesn't work. first of all it doesn't even run as you have the where/from clauses backward in your addition to my statement. second of all it just returns a revno, it doesn't limit the results.

This did however lead me to the right result, as I moved things around and put close to what you had in that last select column in the where clause.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function:

```
;with cte as(
SELECT Docs.DocID
      ,Filename
      ,VName
      ,VText
      ,RevNo
      ,row_number(partition by Docs.DocId, FileName order by RevNo desc) rn
  FROM Docs
  INNER JOIN VarVal ON Docs.DocID = VarVal.DocID
  INNER JOIN Vars ON Vars.VarID = VarVal.VarID
  WHERE Docs.DocID in (
                                    select DocID
                                    from Docs
                                    INNER JOIN VarVal on Docs.DocID = VarVal.DocID
                                    INNER JOIN Var on Var.VarID = VarVal.VarID
                                    where VarName = '07'
                                    and ValueText = '801016'
                                )
  AND Docs.Deleted = 0
  AND Var.IsDeleted = 0)
select * from cte
where rn = 1
```